# How to pass a newly INSERTed row to a function?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions

I have following tables:

```
 table1:       table2:
| uid | did | | uid | did |
|-----+-----| |-----+-----|
| 1   | 2   | | '1' | 2   |
| 4   | 2   | | '4' | 2   |
| 2   | 3   | | '2' | 3   |
| 1   | 8   | | '1' | 8   | 
...
```

I need to create a trigger that would copy every inserted row from `table1` to `table2`, which is on a different schema.

So I made the following function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema1."clone to table2"(uid numeric, did numeric)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO schema2."table2" ("uid", "did")
        VALUES(uid::text, did);
END;
$function$
;
;
```

I have no clue how to pass this function properly to a trigger. After a bit of searching I found this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert
AFTER INSERT 
ON schema1.table1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema1."clone to table2"(new."uid", new."did")
```

However it throws a `"syntax error near ".", Position: 127"`. So I suppose I got it completely wrong.

I know views are perfect solution for my problem but I unfortunately can not use them in my scenario. I just need these two tables to be always identical, with a difference that `table2` needs to have `uid` as `text` type.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yeah, I already noticed how cumbersome it is to work with. But I'm too lazy to revert it, since almost everything I do with the database is abstracted by Entity Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger requires a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). And those can only be written in PL/pgSQL.

So you need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema1.clone_to_table2()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO schema2."table2" ("uid, "did")
  VALUES(new.uid::text, new.did);
  return new;
END;
$function$
;
```

`BEGIN` does not require a `;` at the end.

And then a trigger definition to go with that

```
CREATE TRIGGER on_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON schema1.table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema1.clone_to_table2();
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly as intended.